# NSPredicate to retrieve all objects whose attribute in an 1:n relationship is not NIL

Tags: objective-c, ios, core-data, nspredicate

I would like to build the **NSPredicate** for a **Core Data query** which should retrieve all IBEstPeriod managed objects whose 1:n relationship estType.consHistory.consType <> NIL *.

Unfortunately I have not found any clue on how such a NSPredicate should look like. Do you have any idea or suggestion?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use "ANY" for to-many-relationships in predicates:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[fetchRequest setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"IBEstPeriod" inManagedObjectContext:context]];
[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY estType.consHistory.consType != nil"]];

 NSArray *fetchResult = [managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:nil];
```